# How to remove null parameters in a json rest response?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I'm creating  a `rest` service with `spring` and want to offer a `json` response:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public MyResponse content() {
    return rsp;
}
```

`MyResponse` may contain `null` values which should not be returned in the `JSON` response (these params should just be removed).

```
@XmlRootElement
class MyResponse {
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Which JSON mapper do you use?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just using spring-boot and the `@RestController` annotation.

Comment: Jackson is the default spring json mapper.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class MyResponse {
...
}
```

You'll need to update your dependencies and import this :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
```

Answer (score 7):

Globally remove `null` property.

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion = non_null
```

Comment: That's a very neat trick that is indeed elegant and handy given I almost always annotate all my DTOs with @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL). Thanks !

Comment: I am not sure why this was not marked as an answer. Simple and straight forward yet it works.

Comment: This is really elegant. But I think it works with the latest spring-boot version 2.5.0